# Handle remote notification from within view controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to handle remote notifications from within a specific view controller. I've set my app up so a certain view controller is presented with a specific image in an ImageView when I push a remote notification, but I can't change the image without pushing the same controller again. I'm trying to change the ImageView's image from another remote notification once the view controller has been presented. The idea I had for achieving this, is creating a way to handle remote notifications from within the within the file of the view controller that has just been presented, so the remote notification can edit the ImageView's image. This is how I present the view controller in my AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let data = userInfo["showiMac"] as? [String: String], let iMacConfig = data["iMacConfig"] {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let rootTabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        let firstNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "initialVC1") as! UINavigationController
        rootTabBarController.viewControllers![0] = firstNavigationController

        //the viewController to present
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "configureiMac") as! ConfigureiMacViewController

        // present VC
        firstNavigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: {
            viewController.image = UIImage(named: "iMac" + iMacConfig)
        })

        completionHandler(.noData)


    }
}
```

And here is how image is declared in my view controller:

```
var image: UIImage! 

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     imageView.image = image 
}
```

Comment: Please add the surrounding code including didReceiveRemoteNotification...

Comment: I've just edited the post to include my whole didReceiveRemoteNotification method.

Comment: Since you set the viewController.image, can you show how this variable is declared inside the view controller?

Comment: Definitely. Updated the post once again. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app delegate, do:

```
  weak var configureiMacViewController: ConfigureiMacViewController?
```

Create helper functions to keep your code clean and readable:

```
private func updateiMacImage(_ image: UIImage, in existingViewController: ConfigureiMacViewController) {
    existingViewController.image = image
}

private func showiMacImage(_ image: UIImage) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let rootTabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    let firstNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "initialVC1") as! UINavigationController
    rootTabBarController.viewControllers![0] = firstNavigationController

    //the viewController to present
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "configureiMac") as! ConfigureiMacViewController
    configureiMacViewController = viewController

    // present VC
    firstNavigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: {
        viewController.image = UIImage(named: "iMac" + iMacConfig)
    })
}
```

Then update:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if let data = userInfo["showiMac"] as? [String: String], let iMacConfig = data["iMacConfig"] {
        let image = UIImage(named: "iMac" + iMacConfig)
        if let existingViewController = configureiMacViewController {
           updateiMacImage(image, in: existingViewController)
        } else {
           showiMacImage(image)
        }    
        completionHandler(.noData)
    }
}
```

The weak var in your AppDelegate will store a reference to your view controller but the "weak" keyword will allow the view controller to be released from memory if it is dismissed, in which case the variable will be nil the next time you try to access it.  If the view controller is still visible, then its value will still be defined and you will be able to re-use it to update the image.

You will most likely have to also update your ConfigureiMacViewController code to:

```
var image: UIImage! {
    didSet {
        imageView.image = image
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     imageView.image = image 
}
```

This ensure that if the view controller was already loaded and displayed, but you update the image variable, that the image view is loaded with the most recent image.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for responding so thoroughly. This is super close to working for me, I can feel myself getting close to a solution based on your answer. However, I keep getting an error "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in ConfigureiMacViewController" when I try changing the image. Any ideas on how to avoid that?

Comment: That usually happens when you use ! instead of ? when defining or using variables.  As to which one, I'm not sure

Comment: Ah you're totally right. Thought I had all my variables with ? at the end but I had missed one. Thanks so much man you're a huge help.